# Compute the integral below

Tags: integration, limits

For $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$, define the function $f_n : (0,\infty) → \mathbb{R}$ by:
$$f_n=\left(1+\frac{\ln x^2}{n}\right)^{n}$$
Compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[1,3]}f_n d\lambda$$.

I have been trying to show that: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[1,3]}f_n d\lambda=\int_{[1,3]} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{\ln x^2}{n}\right)^n dλ$$ . But now I don't know how to proceed with the limit anymore. It would be easier if there wasn't any exponential $n$ there, because the fractional part would disappear, anyways this is the one making it harder. Could somebody tell me how to tackle it?

Comment: Try to use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Note that $(1+a/n)^n \to \exp(a)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Using desmos we could see that $f_n \rightarrow x^2$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. To prove this, we need to show that $$x^2-f_n>x^2-f_{n+1}$$ This would require induction, which you could simply make a binomial expansion for $f_{n+1}$ in the second step of the proof. We could now use the fact that $f_n \rightarrow x^2$ to find that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_1^3f_n(x)dx=\int_1^3x^2dx=8\frac{2}{3}$$ If we are integrating with respect to $\lambda$ we get $2x^2$

Comment: But I'm not integrating it w.r.t to x but λ. Does it play any role?

Comment: @Techlover It depends if $f_n$ is a function of $\lambda$ or $x$. It seems like the latter according to the OP which means that the answer is actually $2x^2$.

Comment: It would be assumed that $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure (which, really, in this problem, just treat it like an integral in $x$ a la Calculus II).

Comment: @SeanRoberson never heard of Lebesgue measure, I should search it up.